# Expressing "There are more Fs then Gs" in first-order logic

Tags: model-theory

Is there a sentence of first-order logic that's true in all finite interpretations in which there are more Fs than Gs, and false in all finite interpretations in which there are not more Fs than Gs?

I can see that the answer's "no" without the "finite":

Suppose S is true in *all* interpretations in which there are more Fs then Gs, and take the set of sentences: $\{S, F_1, G_1, F_2, G_2, ...\}$. ($F_n$ "says that" there are at least n Fs, i.e. $F_1$ is $\exists x Fx$, $F_2$ is $\exists x\exists y (x\neq y \wedge Fx \wedge Fy)$, etc). Every finite subset has a model, so the whole set has a countable model, by compactness and L-S, but the set of Fs in this model can't be finite; nor can the set of Gs. So this is a model of S in which there are *not* more Fs than Gs. So if S is true in all interpretations in which there are more Fs then Gs then it can't be true in *only* such interpretations.

But suppose we're not fussed about what happens in the infinite - we just want to draw the distinction among finite interpretations. It *seems* like that shouldn't be possible, either. E.g. if it were, then there would also be a sentence true in all and only finite interpretations, and we know there isn't one of those. Is there a simple proof of this?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such $S$. Let $T=\{\forall x\,(F(x)\leftrightarrow\neg G(x))\}\cup\{F_n,G_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$. Using compactness, $T\cup\{S\}$ and $T\cup\{\neg S\}$ are both consistent, hence they have countable models $M$ and $M'$, respectively. However, the axioms of $T$ guarantee that $M$ and $M'$ both consist of a disjoint union of two countably infinite subsets, one satisfying $F$, and the other satisfying $G$. Thus, $M$ and $M'$ are isomorphic, contradicting $M\models S$ and $M'\models\neg S$.